# Subrings of Chow rings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology, algebraic-cycles

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $\mathbf{F}_p$, call $\overline{X}$ the base change to $\overline{\mathbf{F}}_p$, and denote by $F$ the base change to $\overline{X}$ of the absolute Frobenius of $X$ over $\mathbf{F}_p$.

Call $A$ the Chow ring of cycles up to homological equivalence (defined using, say, $\ell$-adic cohomology, i.e. the image of the cycle map $Z^*(\overline{X}\times \overline{X})\otimes_{\mathbf{Z}}\mathbf{Q}\to H^{2*}(\overline{X}\times \overline{X},\mathbf{Q}_{\ell})(*)$).

Call $R$ the $\mathbf{Q}$-subalgebra of $A$ generated by the classes of the graphs of the endomorphisms $\{F^n, n\ge 1\}$ of $\overline{X}$.

> Is anything at all known about $R$?

Examples of questions I'd be interested in are

- is $R$ known to not be $A$?
- is $R$ a domain, or even a field?
- is $R$ normal?
- does $R$ contain the Lefschetz class?
- is $R$ expected to contain the inverse of the Lefschetz class, perhaps assuming some standard conjectures.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Plenty!

$R$ is generated, as a ring, by $F$. So its structure as a ring is going to be $\mathbb Q(\alpha)/f(\alpha)$, where $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $F$. Because you are using homological equivalence, $f$ is just the least common multiple of the minimal polynomials of the action of $F$ on the various cohomology groups of $X$.

By Deligne's RH, these polynomials are coprime, so it is in fact the product of the minimal polynomials on the different cohomology groups.

Thus $R$ is never a domain unless $X$ is a point.

Since the graphs of powers of $F$ have dimension $n$, $R$ is not equal to $A$ unless every homologically nontrivial cycle on $X \times X$ occurs in degree $n$, i.e. unless $X$ is a point.

Since normal rings are by definition domain, it's not normal.

Because the Lefschetz class lives in dimension $n-1$ and its inverse lies in dimension $n+1$, neither one is contained in this ring since neither has dimension $n$.

Comment: This clarifies everything. Thanks. By "normal" I meant integrally closed in its total ring of fractions, which makes sense when $R$ is not a domain, but the answer is already great as is

Comment: @user178246 This is automatic because it is a ring of one generator.